# Mac osx load dylib inside the binary path instead of /usr/local/lib

Tags: macos, binary, shared-libraries, dylib, lib

i have a protoc binary that needs libprotobuf.20.dylib library, i have the binary and the library in the same folder, what im trying to do is execute the protoc binary using the libprotobuf.20.dylib that is in the same folder instead of "/usr/local/lib".

but when i execute the protoc it says:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libprotoc.20.dylib

is always searching it on /usr/local/lib, how i can change this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reference can be changed:
`install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.20.dylib libprotobuf.20.dylib libprotoc.20.dylib`